# How can I clean memory in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is there any method to clean memory?

I have to do a large fetch requisiton, its about a 4000~~ requests. But, my app crashes because of the large memory consumption. My question is, is there any method to call to clean memory?

Follows the code snippet:

```
function syncFotoProduto(URL, data, auto) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(syncRequest())
        fetch(URL, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data.token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "device_id": data.deviceId,
                "idTipo": 4
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => (([json])))
            .then(([content]) => {
                dispatch(syncFotoProduto(URL, data))
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-clear-app-cache`

> install : `npm install --save react-native-clear-app-cache`
>
> link : `eact-native link react-native-clear-app-cache`

**Example**

```js
   import clear from 'react-native-clear-app-cache'

   clear.clearAppCache(() => {
      console.log("success clear")
    })
```